# ubuntu docker container connect with mongdb running on localhost in windows

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-container

I pulled the ubuntu image and run the container on my windows. I want to connect my MongoDB running locally on windows with ubuntu container. How it is possible or if not what is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: have u tried docker compose?

Comment: Sir please tell in detail I am a beginner.

Comment: Posted my answer. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use [docker-compose network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Let's use a Node app with MongoDB for example.

Your docker-compose file **Docker compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: myapp:latest # your app docker image
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - network
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017 #MongoUrl you can use in your app to connect
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
   volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - network
networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
```

You can connect with the environment variables in Node as below

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const mongodbUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL
const mongoConnectionOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  poolSize: 10,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
}
mongoose
  .connect(mongodbUrl, mongoConnectionOptions)
  .then(async (db) => {
    console.log(`Mongo db ${db.version} is connected`)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. " + err)
  })
```

Then use `docker-compose up` to start these 2 services